# How to insert nested item in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have variable that looks like this.

```
  var $li = $('<li data-session-id="'+this.id+'"><div></div></li>'),
```

I currently append an image like this:

```
  crane.game.waitingList.append($li.append($image));
```

I would like to insert the image inside the div instead, How would I do that?

Answer (score 1):

Use the `find` function: `$li.find("div").append($image)`

Here is a similar example: http://jsfiddle.net/WzL8Y/1/

Another method would be to specify a context in the JQuery Selector:

```
$("div",$li).append($image);
```

Answer (score 1):

`$li` references the list item. To reference the `div` within it, use [`find`](http://api.jquery.com/find):

```
$li.find('div').append($image);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `children()` like this:

```
$li.children(0).append($image)
```